# Reroute audio to speakers on Mac OSX programmatically

Tags: macos, core-audio

How can you redirect audio output to speakers (even when headphones are plugged in) programmatically on Mac OSX with Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View this Post:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48534/is-it-possible-to-play-sound-through-both-the-headphone-jack-and-my-internal-spe

As far as i know, this is not possible. There might be something in here.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW13